# Need NRCS 2008 Common Land Unit (CLU) GIS dataset

Tags: data-request, geospatial, agriculture

I am hoping someone in this group has a copy of the NRCS Common Land Unit GIS coverage. People were looking for it back in 2017 and earlier, but all the sources listed then have dried up. Can anyone help me? I am specifically looking for coverage of northern California.

Comment: Have you contact NRCS in California ? They should be able to give you your answer

Comment: @PROBERT, Yes, and thank you.  That would have been the right ans. prior to 2009, when congress prohibited them from releasing it any more.  Now if you have a pre-2009 copy you are good to go.  If not, you can't get it from NRCS, so am looking for an old personal copy.